# Prove that $\arctan x>x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ using the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\arctan x>x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ using the Mean Value Theorem

You are given that for any $x, y \in [a,b]$, if $y>x$ then $f(y)>f(x)$

I've looked at the answer but I'm not sure I 100% understand the thinking behind it. Can someone explain it clearly please? If you say something like let

$h(x)=\arctan x -x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ you can show that the derivative is always positive, but how/why do you use this?

Answer (score 1):

If $\forall x, h'(x)\geq 0$ than $h$ is monotone increasing. So $\forall x\geq 0, h(x)\geq 0$ and this means

$$\arctan{x}\geq x-\frac{x^3}{3}$$

Let's check $h'$

$$h'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}-1+x^2=\frac{x^4}{x^2+1}\geq 0$$